# how to execute two process in user_data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, sh

I'm studying shell script and aws.

I want to execute flask server and prometheus server in script.

but It doesn't work the way I want it to.

here is my shell script code..

```
#!/bin/bash

. /home/ec2-user/flask/venv/bin/activate
python /home/ec2-user/flask/hello.py 

cd /home/ec2-user/prometheus/prometheus-2.39.1.linux-amd64/
sudo ./prometheus
```

[image: error image]

Shell is waiting after running the "flask server" as shown in the image above.

so prometheus server doesn't work

I want to know how i edit my code

Comment: Are you using the [EC2 user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)?  User data is meant to install services and software on to your machine one time - the first time the EC2 is run.  After that they are not run.  Your shell script should be creating services that run on every reboot.

Comment: Consider accepting my answer since it resolved your question as per your previous comment

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your script is never executed because you are running the Python script in the foreground. Instead, you should run it in the background with `&`:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /home/ec2-user/flask/venv/bin/activate
python /home/ec2-user/flask/hello.py &

cd /home/ec2-user/prometheus/prometheus-2.39.1.linux-amd64/
sudo ./prometheus
```